# Prevent the user from changing the slider value manually : Titanium

Tags: ios, slider, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I'm creating an **ios application** in which the window contains a slider. I'm using the slider for displaying a particular value that has already set, i.e. the user should not change the value manually. I've created the slider as follows

```
var slider = Ti.UI.createSlider({
    min : 0,
    max : 60,
    width : '60%',
    height: 40,
    value : 25,
    enabled : false,
    disabledLeftTrackImage : 'slider.png'
});
```

Here the user in not able to change the slider value because I have set `enabled : false`. But when I do so, the image get blurred(slider 2 in the image). **I want it like the first one and user should not change the slider value manually.** Is it possible to do? Is there any other method to prevent the user from changing the slider value? Can anyone help me?

[image: Slider Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mr.Jack's answer worked fine for me. But I got more Simple way from [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/146682/prevent-the-user-from-changing-the-slider-value-manually--ios-titanium#answer-254217). By resetting the [touchEnabled](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Slider-property-touchEnabled) property like `touchEnabled : false`. I'm adding it here as answer because it will be helpful for someone else!!

```
var slider = Ti.UI.createSlider({
        min : 0,
        max : 60,
        width : '60%',
        height: 40,
        value : 25,
        touchEnabeld : false,
        leftTrackImage : 'slider.png'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are setting `enabled` to `false`, the slider is faded to show the user that it cannot be interacted with. As MaxGabriel said, the equivalent, without fading the slider, is setting `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` in Objective-C. According to this [link](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/140931/disable-user-interaction), the equivalent in Titanium would be to add a clear layer above the slider, so that the user's touches do not get passed to the slider. Here is the code from the link.

```
var overlay_view = Ti.Ui.createView({
    height:'100%',
    width:'100%',
    top:0,
    left:0
})
win.add(overlay_view);
```

Answer (score 1):

Surely this is incorrect UI, why are you using a slider that the user cannot interact with? The correct one to use would be a Ti.UI.ProgressBar, otherwise the enabled:false greyed out behaviour is correct so the user doesn't try to fiddle with it..

Without the context it's being used I don't know but UI convention would suggest the above..

Comment: Markive, I cannot use a progressbar instead of slider. As per requirement i have to use slider to get an uniqueness in the UI.

Comment: You probably need this then: http://boydlee.com/appcelerator-titanium/build-a-custom-image-uploader-progress-bar-in-titanium.html

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C I would set the `userInteractionEnabled` property to `NO`. I presume that translates into `userInteractionEnabled: false` in Titanium?

Comment: Thankyou for your quick response. But I'm not using Objective-C. Titanium does not have a property like that.